# Tag filter system - Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, e2e-testing, cucumberjs, angular-e2e

I am working on a project where there may be several configurations (site for customer A , site for customer B,...). Each configuration has potentially different interactions (it is rare).

So I wrote my code with scenarios for certain configurations.

```
@config1 @config2 @config3
Scenario: A
Given hello


@config1 
Scenario:  B
Given hello  


Scenario: C
Given hello
```

The problem is that I can’t find a solution to say when I’m on config "config3" that I want scenario A and C.

I’ve tested a lot of combinations with `~@config3` or `not @config3`. But I can’t do what I want to do.

Is that even possible?

A big thanks for your help.

Comment: Does `Scenario: C` have any tags?

Comment: no but i can put @all to say that it is executed all the time

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you are trying to combine a scenario with tag and without a tag which might not even possible as per my knowledge.

One solution to this is that you can have a tag on scenario c and combine that with other tags.

Let us assume you have @tagc on scenario c. Then you can use that with other tags to make it work.

if you want to run scenario 1 and 3: (@config3 or @tagc) Scenario 1 and 2: (@config1)

Reference: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags

Comment: Yes but I test with tags on all the scenarios but I think that I cannot manage to structure my exclusion tags

example : 
tags = [
  '(not @config1 and not @config2)',
  '@all',
  '@config3'
]

Comment: if you want to run scenario 1 and 3: (@config3 or @tagc)
Scenario 1 and 2: (@config1)

Comment: @dadadaa, can you please add the command you are using to run the scenarios?

Comment: Thk Raju, it was silly (I had to try to do that today but without success)

Comment: Good. I have included that in my answer.